# SQL View Error - Invalid table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I have imported a sql database using phpmyadmin.  I am receiving the following error:

```
[wrapped: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1356 View 'lingerie_models.view_content_i18n_files_types' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them]
```

all of my tables imported successfully.  I have tried to "check" the database in cPanel, but it shows "ok" through the check, and does not bring up any errors.

The site was made using Symphony.

Please can someone assist me with what could be causing this error?

Links to the site are as follows:
[Frontend_dev.php](http://lingeriemodel.co.za/web/frontend_dev.php)

Please advise if there is any additional information which is required in order to assist?

I have no SQL knowledge, and will appreciate any guidance in this regard

Thank you